# How to remove or change color of Vim's sign column?

Tags: vim, neovim

How can I change the color of the marked white bar appearing before line numbers when there is any warning as shown

[image]

Comment: `:hi SignColumn`

Comment: FYI, it's called *sign column* in Vim's `:help` but is commonly referred to as *gutter*. The things that indicate warnings are called *signs*. See `:help signs`.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find it using :hi but I was confused as there are tons of other things alongside. This helped

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Friedrich Have no clue what  you mean. I'm trying to point him to the vi/vim stack exchange where he might better find his answer.

Comment: @Rob I understand you mean well. The consensus seems to be not to advertise other SE sites in this way because of the danger of cross-posting. I have been guilty of the same crime, btw. If you think this question belongs on Vi & Vim SE, raise a vote to have it migrated there. SO offers *much* faster answers so users may deliberately rather ask here. I just don't see how posting that link without any context is supposed to help anyone.

Comment: @Friedrich Some time ago, a mod I think, chastised me as vim being a programming tool and that the question belongs here. I disagree but now only provide the link hoping the questioner learns of the resource and I guess I now understand why you pointed me there and I agree with you.